# What area of mathematics is this problem asking about?

Tags: logic, puzzle, problem-solving

A colleague posted this on a whiteboard (as a brain-teaser I guess):

---

A $\rightarrow$ B;
B $\rightarrow$ C;
AD $\rightarrow$ E;
BE $\rightarrow$ C;
BF $\rightarrow$ D;
AC $\rightarrow$ F

What is the minimum set I need to determine A, B, C, D, E, and F?

---

I'm not interested in help solving the problem.  I'd just like to know the general domain of the problem because it's not clear to me.  It probably is clear to a mathematics community.

For example, does it deal with set theory, or logic?  Or some other area of math?

Comment: If you had some notion of what $\to$ means and what juxtaposing two symbols means, then it could be viewed as a group-theoretic problem.

Comment: Ask your colleague.

Comment: I dont quite follow. In order to determine A, you need not B. In order to determine C you need B. What is the resolution?

Comment: @Adam I have no idea. I probably should just delete the question. I just wanted at the time to see if I could come up with the correct answer without asking my colleagues about the notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first interpreted this as a dependency graph, with $pq\to r$ meaning that if you know $p$ and $q$, then you can find $r$, or that tasks $p$ and $q$ are prerequisites for $r$, or something of that sort.

Understood this way, then it is a problem of graph theory, to find the source vertices of the directed graph determined by the given relations.  There is one source, $A$, because from $A$ we can get to $B$ and to $C$; then from $AC$ we get to $F$; from $BF$ we get to $D$; and from $AD$ we get to $E$.

But I have no way to be sure that this is the intended interpretation.  It might mean something completely different.  For example, $pq\to r$ might mean that if $p$ and $q$ are riding in the same taxi then $r$ cannot ride there too, and the question is to find the minimum required number of taxis; then the answer is very different. Or it might be as Jonathan Christensen says, which is different again.  Or perhaps $pq\to r$ means that whenever you have letters $p$ and $q$ adjacent in a word, you can replace them with $r$, and the question is to find the number of English words that transform into other English 
words.

Without more explanation from your colleague, I don't think the question can be reasonably answered.

Comment: I think that the question at the end of the problem just about rules out the taxi interpretation and the word interpretation: the questions don’t fit. Jonathan’s interpretation is essentially the same as the dependency graph interpretation: just substitute ‘if $p$ and $q$ are true, then so is $r$’ for ‘if you know $p$ and $q$, then you can find $r$’.

Answer (score 4):

It's logic. A-F are either true or false, and the question is which ones you need to know (at a minimum) to determine the truth of all six of them.

Edit: AB means "A and B," the arrow is implication.

Comment: How do you know?